# How to get the "Display name" of a Window's device (not "Friendly name" or "Device description")

Tags: windows, device-driver

Devices in the `Device Manager` of Windows have, among many others, these properties (in the "Details" tab): `Hardware Ids`, `Device description` and `Friendly name`

Each have equivalent constant:

```
SPDRP_HARDWAREID: Hardware Ids
SPDRP_DEVICEDESC: Device description
SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME: Friendly name
```

As appear in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But I could not find anywhere the value of the `Display name` property. So where can I find it?

Comment: Typically, "display name" and "friendly name" are the same thing.  Are you sure `SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME` doesn't give you the information you want?  Have you tried it?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, only devices (leaves in the devices tree) have "friendly name". Bridges don't, and their "display name" is their "Description" (the "friendly name" is `null` in their case)

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that the "display name" actually exists as a property?  I can't see it in the [device driver documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  My guess is that the Windows GUI simply shows you the friendly name if it exists and the description otherwise, and you can do the same thing.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, actually I believe that "display name" is a function that returns "description" in case it's a device (leaf), and the "friendly name" in case it's a bridge (node)